# Firefox keeps showing scrollbars for iframes. How to hide them

Tags: html, firefox, iframe

Original link: http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?235680-FF-has-problems-with-IFrames-scrolling-and-height

I was always a fan of FireFox but now I am starting to hate it. I am changing my page to have IFrames and now FireFox is a pain in the ass, whereas IE works like a charm!

I have my Iframe as follows:
Code:

```
<iframe id="leftiframe" src="<?=$page?>" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" style="overflow:visible; width:100&#37;;">
</iframe>
```

But FireFox keeps on showing me Scrollbars in my IFrame, where `scrolling=no`. Why doesn't FireFox understand I don't want scrollbars. Furthermore the size of the IFrame is not reported correctly within FireFox. Not with `offsetHeight`, `clientHeight`, `scrollHeight` or whatever.

Comment: It should be noted that removing the scrollbars from an `<iframe>` is pretty stupid. It can prevent the user from being able to see the content of it if using a small screen resolution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The iframe scrolling attribute is not supported in HTML5. You need to use CSS to remove the scrollbars.

```
#leftiframe {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```